# How to make intellisense works to show functions with arguments?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I am having a big c# form with more than 90+ functions. The programmer who coded this some months back left the company. Its difficult to recognize which word he have used for which function. So i want an easy solution.

Want I dont want is ,

1) I dont want to rename all the function names

Want I want is ,

To modify the intellisense to show the arguments a function has , but my default settings allow me to see the function only in the intellisense and not the arguments inside it.

Is there any third party tools or intellisense modifiers / tools to do this ??

Comment: You'd have to write an extension for 2008 in order to change how intellisense behaves.  It would be easier to delete everything that programmer did and start from scratch.

Comment: There is some commercial add-ins for VisualStudio All versions but I don't know exactly how they show intellisense.